# Managing redux state for a list of items

Tags: reactjs, redux

Prior to this, I was managing general Redux state as follows:
for example I was setting `isRequestTags` from a reducer.
But now I'm facing another challenge:
Suppose I have a list of tags, for each tag there can be some states defined like `isPrimaryTag`.
How can I define states for a list of items which have a common attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of tags, and each tag has, say, a name and a flag, then you can't "refactor" that out in any meaningful way, e.g.,

```
tags: [
    { name: 'foo', isPrimary: true  },
    { name: 'bar', isPrimary: false }
]
```

If the common attributes are *themselves* an object, particularly a large one, you'd use normal state-shape practices as [outlined in the Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html).

For example, if each tag had something like this:

tagInfo: {
    isPrimary: true,
    group: 'whatever',
    somethingElse: { etc: 'etc' }
}

*and* multiple tags had the same value, you'd provide an ID/index:

```
tagInfos: [
    {
        isPrimary: true,
        group: 'whatever',
        somethingElse: { etc: 'etc' }
    },

    {
        isPrimary: true,
        group: 'whatever',
        somethingElse: { etc: 'etc' }
    }
]

tags: [
    { name: 'foo', tagInfoIndex: 0 },
    { name: 'bar', tagInfoIndex: 1 }
    // etc
]
```

All that said, I'm not entirely sure if that's what you're asking.

Comment: let me give you an example: suppose I have a list of blogs, each blog has many tags. When I navigate to say ``/blog/first-blog`` I want to know whether that specific blog's tags have been fetched. So I could specify that state attributes like: ``hasTags:false, tags:[]``. but when I'm dealing with a list of blogs I don't know how to specify these attributes. If there were any confusions ask me please. thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad It depends on how your app works. If you want to keep the content of multiple blogs in state at the same time then you'd have a collection of blogs, indexed or as a hash. Each blog's tags would go in that blog's data (object). You specify them the same way you deal with *any* object, e.g., `blogs: { 'blog1': { hasTags: someBool, tags: [] }, 'blog2': { ... } }` If you're keeping only a single blog in the store then there's no issue.

Comment: actually the opposite way, I want to have another separate attribute: ``hasTags`` and ``tags`` which is generic. when the user navigates to ``/blogs/blog-one`` I want to check if I have tags for that blog (via ``hasTags`` state) if not, fetch tags for that blog and put it in ``tags`` state. Can something like this be achieved?

Comment: @Mehrdad You want to have multiple blogs, but a single thing for tags? That doesn't make a lot of sense.